# Uncommon subjunctive inversion in a negative clause in the pluperfect: "had not millions been swept away"

Tags: word-order, negation, subjunctive-mood, past-perfect

> Voters in 2008 would have seen he didn’t measure up then, **had not millions been swept away** with emotion and wish-fulfillment. ([source](https://www.denverpost.com/2012/03/23/andrews-imagining-a-romney-santorum-ticket/))

This line reads odd even jarring to me with a weird inversion word order in the second clause. The common way of writing pluperfect (past perfect) subjunctive sentences is:

> Voters in 2008 would have seen he didn’t measure up then, **had millions not been swept away** with emotion and wish-fulfillment.
>
> **Had it not been for her**, I wouldn't have found it. (as opposed to **Had not it been for her, I wouldn't have found it.*)

Is the inversion in sentence at issue valid as well? I thought it could be the result of the writer's stylistic choice, but it just sounds plain wrong to my ear. Archaic? Possible? Or just plain wrong?

Comment: Inverted auxiliaries like _had_ shouldn't drag _not_ along with them; better would be _had millions not been swept away_, with the negative in its original position. Better still would be not to indulge in archaic constructions unless writing an operetta.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, that is why I wonder if the form in question is archaic and has historical attestations.

Comment: You can't contract it and still front it; at least I can't. *_It would have been nice, hadn't millions been swept away with emotion and wish-fulfillment_. Even worse with the whole clause fronted: *_Hadn't millions been swept away with emotion and wish-fulfillment, it would have been nice._